# RequireJS load string

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In my app there are dynamic parts that are loaded from database as string that looks like:

```
"define(['dependency1', 'dependency2'], function(){"+
"   // function body" +
"})"
```

which is just a simple requireJS module, as a string. I want to lazy load the script above using async require call. So, my main requireJS script looks like:

```
require(["jquery"], function($){        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // logic to load specific script from database
        var scriptString = functionToLoadTheStringAbove();

        // ideally i would like to call it like this            
        require([scriptString], function(){
           // scriptString, dependency1, dependency2 are loaded
        }
    });
});
```

How do I load those string in requireJS? I know about text plugin, but it only allow loading from files. I tried eval but it doesn't resolve dependencies correctly.

Comment: please be clear while asking any question. Please refeame your question.

Comment: Oh my, are you really storing evaluable code in database like this?

Comment: Yes. In my case it was in browser extension. So, no choice of creating REST endpoint / saving dynamic code in filesystem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite late, but I just post my solution here in case anyone needs.

So I ended up asking in requireJS forum and examining the source of [text! plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) and [json! plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/blob/master/src/json.js). The cleanest way to load module from String in RequireJS is by making your own plugin to load the String, and then use [onLoad.fromText()](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html#apiload) that will `eval` your String and resolve all dependencies.

Example of my plugin (let's call it `db!` plugin):

```
define([], function(){
    var db = new Database(); // string is loaded from LocalStorage
    return {
        load: function(name, req, onLoad, reqConfig){
            db.get(name, function(err, scriptString){
                if (err) onLoad(err);
                else onLoad.fromText(scriptString);
            });  
         }
    }
});
```

You can then use the plugin like:

```
require(["jquery", "db!myScript"], function($, myScript){        
    // jQuery, myScript and its dependencies are loaded from database
});
```

*Note:*

1. There's no way to `require()` from String without `eval`. This is what `onLoad.fromText()` does internally. Since eval is evil, you should only use it if you know what String you're going to `eval()`. If you're using it in browser extension, you might want to relax the CSP policy.
2. To name your String module, you can use [explicit naming syntax](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename). This way, your module will always have the same absolute name.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question a little more directly, create a [plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html) like so:

```
define("load-string",[], function(){
    var strings=[],
        re_package_name = /^string_module_(\d+)$/;
    return {
        normalize: function(name, _){
            if(re_package_name.test(name)){
                return name
            }
            var nml = "string_module_" + (strings.push(name)-1);
            return nml;
        },
        load: function(name, _, onLoad, config){
            if(re_package_name.test(name)){
                onLoad.fromText(strings[name.match(re_package_name)[1]]);
            }else{
                onLoad.error("Invalid package name: ",name);
            }
        }  
    }
});
```

and use it like so:

```
var world_module = "define([],function(){return 'world!'})";

require(["load-string!" + world_module],
    function(x){
        console.log("Hello "+x);
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do :

```
require(["jquery"], function($){        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // logic to load specific script from database
        var scriptString = functionToLoadTheStringAbove();

        var olddefine = define; // require js define 
        var runme; // capture function 
        define = function (args,func){
             runme = func; 
        }
        eval(scriptString);
        runme(); // run the function in current scope
        define = olddefine; // restore requirejs function 

        // dependency1, dependency2 are loaded        
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. running runme() only doesn't resolve dependencies + we lose scope / closure offered by require.

Comment: I like seeing this answer, just to see confirmation that it's wrong :)